# Reference a cell that is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to reference a cell in the delegate method, didSelectRowAt using this code:

```
 if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: expandedIndexPath!) as? FeedInsertTableCollectionViewCell{}
```

That cell is not in the view (not visible) at the time it is being referenced and is therefore not dequeued anymore. Because it is not in the view, the if let statement above is failing. How do I reference a cell that is not in the view?

To give you a better idea of what I am looking to do. When a user clicks a cell, I need to clear the data from a previous cell and load data into the cell that the user clicked. Because the above if let statement is failing, I am not able to clear the data in the previous cell because I am not able to reference or access it.

Comment: You don't need to access either cell. Update your data model used by your table's data source and then tell the table view to reload the affected index paths.

Comment: Cells which are *not in the view* do not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small project to show one way it can be done. Git it [enter link description here](https://github.com/TeamPacMan/PreviousCellTapped)

How does it work?

A property is declared where the latest clicked cells will be stored:

```
var lastSelectedCells = [IndexPath]()
```

Since we want to have the latest clicked cell at the top of that array, here's what we do in the method "DidSelectCellAtRowIndexPath":

```
lastSelectedCells.insert(indexPath, at: 0)
```

We also want to update the cells that has been clicked before (including the current one), so, right after the above we execute:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: lastSelectedCells, with: .automatic)
```

The rest of the logic is in the "CellForRowAtIndexPath" method, as follows (a bit simplified compared to the project):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NiceCell") as! MyBeautifulCell 
        if let index = lastSelectedCells.index(of: indexPath) {
            cell.centeredLabel?.text = "Cell tapped \(index) times ago!"
        } else {
            cell.centeredLabel?.text = "Uhmpf, this cell was never tapped!"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

That is: if the current indexPath is in the array, we set the text of the cell to be its index, otherwise we set some grumpy text.

I'm not aware of your entire project, but this should be enough for you to achieve what are you trying to do.

Since you say: I need to clear data in the previous cells...
you may change the method as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NiceCell") as? MyBeautifulCell else {
            fatalError("Table Configuration Error!")
        }

        if let index = lastSelectedCells.index(of: indexPath) {
            switch index {
            case 0:
                cell.centeredLabel?.text = "Cell tapped"
            default:
                cell.centeredLabel?.text = "CLEARED"
            }
        } else {
            cell.centeredLabel?.text = "Uhmpf, this cell was never tapped!"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

If you go this way, the reloadRows implementation can reload only the second last row, but this would be an optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) after you have updated your data model. The [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview) will then ask your [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) to provide the corresponding cell with the new data.

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [expandedIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
```